# Convert date and time in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, date-conversion

How can I convert the string,

```
yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:SSS
```

To,

```
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm AM/PM
```

Hope our stack users will help me.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Is the first value a `String` or `Date`?  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Did you try looking at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: You can parse the first format and out put it as the second format.  Note: in Java `MM` means Months and `mm` means minutes and `DD` doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Parse the string using `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"` and then format using `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"` . Haven't tried it though !

Comment: Caps YYYY makes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. So change that to.

Comment: Please do a search, questions about parsing and formatting dates are one of the most frequently asked questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
            SimpleDateFormat dfFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"),
                            dfTo = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");

            System.out.println(dfTo.format(dfFrom.parse("2013-01-02 14:59:27.953")));
    }
```

Regards,

AKDA

Comment: you may have to switch **MM** and **dd**, it's not clear from your example which part is the month and which one is the day

Comment: Got the exact answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply change the output format, you could use `.format()` from [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat simple = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
String s = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a").format(simple);
```

You do not specify if you actually want to use a `Date` object, but nonetheless, you can use the above method to perform the conversion that you desire.

If you wish to use a `SimpleDateFormat`, but actually want to change the internal format, use `applyPattern()`:

```
simple.applyPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your time format is wrong MM for month, mm for minutes

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm AM/PM
```

instead of

```
MM/DD/yyyy HH:MM AM/PM
```

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Try this,

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/yyyy HH:mm a");
System.out.println("Formated Date : "+simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  String dateTime="2013-01-02 14:59:27.953";
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");
    Date date=df.parse(dateTime);
    df=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/yyyy hh:mm a");
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    Test() throws ParseException {
  SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat();
        String dateString = "2013-01-02 14:59:27.953";
        sd.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date date = sd.parse(dateString);
        sd.applyPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a");
        System.out.println(sd.format(date));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
           new Test();
        } catch(ParseException e) {
           System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```